# Aligning numbered paragraphs

Tags: latex

I am trying to cross reference some numbered paragraphs. I am using \numpar but the first one always is off aligned. (\item didn't work)

Here is what I did:

```
\section{First section}
\subsection*{Subsection1}
\numpar\label{A1} blablabla1
\numpar\label{A2} blablabla2
\numpar\label{A3} blablabla3

\section{Second section}
Statement \ref{A2} = 2 must be true.
```

which results in:

[image]

I need all numbers to be aligned without affecting on unnumbered paragraphs. I am open to other commands instead of \numpar if any. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Please put in an [MCVE]. In particular, how did you create `\numpar`? The code block needs to be a copy-paste reproduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `enumerate`? It is done for that kind of problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection*{Subsection1}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{A1} blablabla1
\item \label{A2} blablabla2
\item \label{A3} blablabla3
\end{enumerate}
\section{Second section}
Statement \ref{A2} = 2 must be true.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If required, you can customize the appearance with the enumitem package.

For instance, to increase the indentation, load the package, and start enumerate with :

```
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=3cm]`
```

Many options in the enumitem package and it can certainly fit your needs.

Edit:
Note that \item will indent anything that is after it. If you dont want this behavior, close the enumerate before your paragraph. Then you can restart the enumerate, but you must take care of the item numbering (see below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection*{Subsection1}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{A1} blablabla1

  This paragraph will be indented

\end{enumerate}

But this one will not.

\begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{1}
  % This insures that item numbering will be coherent
  % set it to the value of the last item
  % If using the enumitem package, there is a simpler way with 'resume'
  % \begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item \label{A2} blablabla2
\item \label{A3} blablabla3
\end{enumerate}

And another non indented par

\section{Second section}
Statement \ref{A2} = 2 must be true.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the enumerate. If I don't put it just before the first \numpar I get an error. Once I put enumerate before the first \numpar, the rest of the chapter is indented. How can I fix it, so no paragraph becomes indented? Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry! I meant \item, not \numpar! \Item indents all my chapter! How can I fix it? Thanks! I just need to number some paragraphs and later reference them.

Comment: Here is the \numpar that I have:

\newcounter{para}
\newcommand\numpar{\refstepcounter{para}\thepara .\space}
But this one does not work properly neither. It does not indent the first one.

Comment: \item is *not* supposed to indent anything but what is between the \begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate}. Close enumerate to have normal indenting. See edits in the answer.

Comment: So I cannot have one \begin{enumerate} and \end{enumerate} in my chapter? Should I use them every time I want to number a paragraph? Is there any easier way?

Comment: It depends on what you want. enumerate will number the paragraph **and** indent it (first and successive lines). If you just want paragraph numbering, but no indenting (except for the first line of the paragraph), your \numpar command is perfect. No indenting on first line of the first paragraph in a section is normal LaTeX behavior, numbering or not. You can change that globally by the indentfirst package. And you can modify it on demand by adding \hspace{\parindent}  before the first paragraph of a section if you want to indent it.

Comment: Thanks so much! \hspace{\parindent} solved the problem with the \numpar and I used them.